# How to ignore Sonars Duplicate Code Block Warning

Tags: java, sonarqube

Let say I have a class like this.

```
public class ApplicationInfoDTO implements IdInc {

private String applicationName;
private String description;
private String version;
private String releaseDate;
private List<String> registeredServicesList;
... and soome other fields
```

All the fields are marked by Sonar as duplicated Code Block, actually it make no sense to rename fields or solve this with inheritance.

At this point I want to ignore this warning. I put a // NOSONAR like this.

```
public class ApplicationInfoDTO implements IdInc { // NOSONAR
```

also I try it with // NOSONAR after a package declaration. Both not worked.

How I can add an ignore flag?

Comment: maybe put it next to one of the attributes? Aside from this, you can disable duplicate code warnings altogether if you want this.

Comment: Also not worked.

Answer (score 2):

On official documentation, there is a page about [Narrowing the Focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/)

> SonarQube gives you several options for configuring exactly what will
> be analyzed. You can
>
> - completely ignore some files or directories
> - exclude files/directories    from Coverage calculations but analyze all other aspects
> - ***exclude files/directories from Duplications detection but analyze all other    aspects***
> - exclude files/directories from Issues detection (specific rules or all of them) but analyze all other aspects

There you can find **Ignore Duplications** section:

> **Ignore Duplications**
>
> You can prevent some files from being checked for duplications.
>
> To do so, go to Project Settings > General Settings > Analysis Scope >
> Duplications and set the Duplication Exclusions property. See the
> Patterns section for more details on the syntax.